# MVC ASP.NET MVC3 AllowHtml Attribute Not Working?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

The question is very simple:

Say you have a model called Person

```
public class Person
{

       public int PersonID {get; set;}

       public string Name {get; set;}

       [AllowHtml] // Allow html in Intro property
       public string Intro {get; set;}

       [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
       public string ComplicatedValue {get; set;}

}
```

In controller's Create action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Person o, FormCollection collection)
{

// whatever code here;

}
```

If you run it,

1. input plain text for Intro, no
   problem happens.
2. input html content for Intro, no matter how you set
   your configuration file, it will
   tells "A potential dangerous ..."

**I DO find the reason of this problem.**

If you change the function to

```
public ActionResult Create(Person o) // Get rid of the *FormCollection collection*
{

// whatever code here;

}
```

This will eliminate the "potential dangerous" error.

**But my problem** is that for my application, I have to use the secondary parameter **FormCollection collection** in the Create Action method, because I need to use some other control values and server variable to assign a calculated value to the **ComplicatedValue** property.

If any expert of ASP.NET MVC3 have met the same problem as me, and found a solution, please kindly let me know.

Answer (score 8):

This forum at this link discusses this issue at length and gives some workarounds.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1621677/4161637.aspx

Here is one solution from that thread that may or may not work for you:

```
public ActionResult Create(Person o) // Get rid of the *FormCollection collection*
{    
FormCollection form = new FormCollection(Request.Unvalidated().Form);
// whatever code here;
}
```

or my own recommendation:

```
public ActionResult Create(Person o, int otherControlValue1, int otherControlValue2, ...)
{        
      o.ComplicatedValue = CalculateComplicatedValue(otherControlValue1, otherControlValue2, ...);
      // whatever code here.

}
```

In my case, I am not using the FormCollection, but it was there so that I had a different footprint on my [HttpPost] method. I did this hack and put in a bogus parameter:

```
public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    return View(this.repository.GetById(id));
}
[HttpPost]
public virtual ActionResult Edit(int id, int? bogusID)
{            
    var d = repository.GetById(id);
    if (TryUpdateModel(d))
    {
        repository.Save();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: The answer has helped us for solving problem. Thanks lot!

Comment: The top example worked for me, except I had to remove the extra `()` from `Request.Unvalidated().Form` to just have `Request.Unvalidated.Form`

Comment: Instead of the bogus parameter, just do different function name (e.g. Update(int id)), and mark with attribute ActionName("Edit").

Answer (score 2):

Might I suggest using a custom model binder instead of pulling the complex data from a FormCollection.  Scott Hanselman has a [blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx) post on creating a custom model binder that would serve as a good template.  In his post he puts together a DateTimeModelBinder that allows a DateTime property to be set either by a single input containing the date or a pair of inputs containing a date and a time.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried

> *[Bind(**Exclude**="ComplicatedValue")]*

:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude="ComplicatedValue")]Person o)
{
}
```

?

with that it allows you to exclude setting **ComplicatedValue** property on the form and still submit the object as a **Person** class.

hope that helps

Comment: Actually that excludes the o.ComplicatedValue property but it remains in FormCollection so the error will still be triggered.